# How to set a global variable while the user is logged in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to set a global variable, while the user is logged in. I need to be able to access this variable with both controllers and Views.

I am currently using the built-in MVC Membership provider.

A user must not be able to edit this variable in any way.

I have tried using Session, but this expires at some point, while the user is still logged in.

Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You can use session cookies, encrypted values if security is a concern.  Also take a look at the Application object which is global for the running application, not per user as the session object.

Answer (score 0):

A technique I employed for my own needs was to create a `BaseController` which inherits `Controller` and then have my various controllers inherit that.  In the `BaseController` I put my "global" variable, which was set via the `BaseController` constructor.  All controller actions then could access this variable and make it available to other things (views, models) as necessary.  It worked quite well in my situation.

Comment: Interesting idea. The value that i need to make global comes from the database. Would the BaseController get it from the database every time i need to use a Controller which inherits it, or only once per session/login?

Comment: @Nanek - If you made a `static` property in the `BaseController`, I believe what you'd get is that *every* controller would have access to that value and be able, depending on your implementation, to change it - open a two browsers and they share it, at least it works that way here in my dev environment.  That might not be what you want.  Setting the `BaseController`'s constructor as a `static` rather than `protected` constructor means it gets called once.  You could certainly throw some logic in there to avoid tapping the DB if you didn't need/want to continually get it from the DB.

Comment: @Nanek - If you had a `protected BaseControler()` constructor, it's going to get called once for every instantiation, of course, of derived controller class.  Might not be ideal.

Comment: Nice. I need to have access to User.Identity.Name - the BaseController does not have this. Howcome?